# How are docker layer directories named?

Tags: docker, docker-image

In the description of how a docker image is structured ([here](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/image/spec/v1.2.md#combined-image-json--filesystem-changeset-format)) the spec shows that there is a directory for each layer. It states

> There is a directory for each layer in the image. Each directory is named with a 64 character hex name that is deterministically generated from the layer information. These names are not necessarily layer DiffIDs or ChainIDs.

Somewhat frustratingly, they don't say *how* those names are derived from the layer information, although this might appear elsewhere in the document (though looking over it I've been unable to find it).

What is the algorithm to derive the layer directory names? Perhaps the name doesn't matter as long as it's deterministically chosen?